# Java Synchronized account example isn't working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm using Account example to practice the Java Synchronized.
And here is my code.

**Account class**

```
class Account {

public int dollars;

public Account(int d) {
    dollars = d;
}

// might fail due to concurrently accessing this method
public synchronized void deduct2(int amount) {
      dollars -= amount;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + dollars;
}
```

**MyThread class**

```
 class MyThread extends Thread {
static Account account = new Account(10000);

private int id;

public MyThread(int i) {
    id = i;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("performing my job ....");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        account.deduct2(1);
        System.out.println("account " + account + "  " + getName() +"performing....");
    }
}
```

**ThreadTest class**

```
public class ThreadTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new ThreadTest().exec();
    System.out.println("main finished");
}

private void exec() {
    test1();
}

private void test1() {
    Thread thread1 = new MyThread(1);
    Thread thread2 = new MyThread(2);
    Thread thread3 = new MyThread(3);
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

}}
```

**Result**

> main finished
> performing my job ....
> performing my job ....
> performing my job ....
> account 9997  Thread-0performing....
> account 9997  Thread-2performing....
> account 9997  Thread-1performing....
> account 9995  Thread-2performing....
> account 9996  Thread-0performing....
> account 9993  Thread-2performing....
> account 9994  Thread-1performing....
> account 9991  Thread-2performing....
> account 9992  Thread-0performing....
> account 9989  Thread-2performing....
> account 9990  Thread-1performing....
> account 9987  Thread-2performing....
> account 9988  Thread-0performing....
> account 9985  Thread-2performing....
> account 9986  Thread-1performing....
> ....
> account 9713  Thread-1performing....
> account 9708  Thread-1performing....
> account 9709  Thread-0performing....
> account 9706  Thread-0performing....
> account 9707  Thread-1performing....
> account 9704  Thread-1performing....
> account 9705  Thread-0performing....
> account 9702  Thread-0performing....
> account 9703  Thread-1performing....
> account 9701  Thread-0performing....
> account 9700  Thread-1performing....

I run three different new Thread, and every new thread deduct 1 for an hundred times. So the result of account dollars is correct(9700). 
But I'm confused why the process of account dollars were being deduct is not working as my expected. I assume it would runs like 9999 9998 9997.....

Comment: Because your print statement is not part of any synchronization, it sees whatever values.

Comment: Thanks! I know where's problem now.

Comment: Then consider to accept the answer you got ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `System.out.println` is not sync, for example:

1. At the beginning dollers was 10000
   , `thread1` and `thread2` execute `account.deduct2(1)`; Now dollers is 9998.
2. `thread3` execute `account.deduct2(1)`; Now dollers is 9997.
3. `thread1` and `thread2` start printing `account#dollars`, you will see two `9997`.

If you want to print sequentially, put the `synchronized` in for loop.(`Account#deduct2` does not need to add `synchronized` anymore.):

```
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            synchronized (account) {
                account.deduct2(1);
                System.out.println("account " + account + "  " + getName() + "performing....");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm wondering this question for a while...... You guys help me a lot.